# How to use Controls in sharepoint without using the spcontext.current

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, controls

Sharepoint Controls require SPContext.current.site/web to work, but i am opening many sites using site= new spsite(siteID); and i want to use Controls. So do u have any idea or available class to use asp.net controls in sharepoint?

Comment: Could you please provide more information like how are you creating control objects and what exceptions you receive when trying to use them?

Thank you.

Comment: ok, i will write in the answers area because my reply is too big to fit here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//open site and web
sSiteID = Request.QueryString["siteID"];
sWebID = Request.QueryString["parentWebID"];
site = new SPSite(new Guid(sSiteID));
web = site.OpenWeb(new Guid(sWebID));
//show the properties of the list in the edit form
(...)
if ((list.AllowContentTypes == true) && (list.ContentTypesEnabled == true))
{
    (...)
    SharePointWebControls oSharePointWebControls = new SharePointWebControls(); 

    cntrl = oSharePointWebControls.GetSharePointControls(field, list, item, SPControlMode.Edit, "");
}

public Control GetSharePointControls(SPField field, SPList list, SPListItem item, SPControlMode mode, string strType)
{
    switch (field.FieldRenderingControl.ToString())
    {
        case "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TextField":
            return CreateTextFieldControl(field, list, item, mode);
    }
}

#region Create SharePoint Controls
private static Control CreateTextFieldControl(SPField field, SPList list, SPListItem item, SPControlMode mode)
{
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    //tf.EnableViewState=false;
    tf.ListId = list.ID;
    if (item != null)
    {
        tf.ItemId = item.ID;
    }
    tf.FieldName = field.Title;
    tf.ID = "Field_" + field.Id;
    //tf.CssClass = "spsControl";
    tf.ControlMode = mode;
    //check if the field has a default value
    if (field.DefaultValue != "null" && field.DefaultValue != null)
    {
        tf.Text = field.DefaultValue.ToString();
    }
    try
    {
        RequiredFieldValidator cntrlValidator = ((RequiredFieldValidator)tf.Controls[0].Controls[3]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return tf;
}
```

all sharepoint controls i am using are working and tf is returned correctly, but when i am not in the current site or the current web
this exception occured : InvalidArgumentException in the control.
I guess these controls does not work outside the current site or web, and i have to use asp.net control? Is it right or is there another solution? Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you format the code and move it to the question itself? You essentially need to fake the spcontext and load the other sitecollection to it.

Answer (score 0):

Fake Spcontext is the solution for your problem.
google it, it might help you.